# maximum degree of a line graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want  to prove that $\Delta(L_{G})+1 \leq 2\Delta(G)-1 $   where $\Delta(G) $ is the maximum degree of the graph G,  and $L_{G}$ is the line graph of the graph G.
I know that every vertex of degree k in the original graph creates $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ edges in the line graph but can figure out where the inequality and  the change of the sign of 1 comes from.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes sorry I had missed a 2 in front of the maximum degree of G. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If $e=uv$ is an edge of graph $G$, then
$$
\operatorname{deg}_{L(G)}(e)=\operatorname{deg}_G(u)+\operatorname{deg}_G(v)-2.
$$